# Scrapy bypass data usage consent wall

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, yahoo-finance

I am scraping yahoo finance news using the code below.

```
class YfinNewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yfin_news_spider'
    custom_settings = {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': '0.5', 'COOKIES_ENABLED': True, 'COOKIES_DEBUG': True}

    def __init__(self, month, year, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/sitemap/2020_03_all']
        self.allowed_domains = ['finance.yahoo.com']
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        all_news_urls = response.xpath('//ul/li[@class="List(n) Py(3px) Lh(1.2)"]')
        for news in all_news_urls:
            news_url = news.xpath('.//a[@class="Td(n) Td(u):h C($c-fuji-grey-k)"]/@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(news_url, callback=self.parse_news, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_news(self, response):
        news_url = str(response.url)
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
        paragraphs = response.xpath('//div[@class="caas-body"]/p/text()').extract()
        date_time = response.xpath('//div[@class="caas-attr-time-style"]/time/@datetime').extract_first()

        yield {'title': title, 'url': news_url, 'body_text': paragraphs, 'timestamp': date_time}
```

However, when I run my spider it give me below results.

```
2020-11-28 20:42:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId=3_cc-session_05cc09ea-0bc0-439d-8b4c-2d6f20f52d6e> (referer: https://finance.yahoo.com/sitemap/2020_03_all)
2020-11-28 20:42:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/news/onegold-becomes-first-company-offer-110000241.html>
Cookie: B=cnmvgrdfs5a0r&b=3&s=o1; GUCS=ASXMbR9p
2020-11-28 20:42:40 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId=3_cc-session_05cc09ea-0bc0-439d-8b4c-2d6f20f52d6e>
{'title': 'Yahoo er nu en del af Verizon Media', 'url': 'https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId=3_cc-session_05cc09ea-0bc0-439d-8b4c-2d6f20f52d6e', 'body_text': [], 'timestamp': None}
2020-11-28 20:42:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId=3_cc-session_d6731ce6-78bc-4222-914f-24cf98f874b8> (referer: https://finance.yahoo.com/sitemap/2020_03_all)
```

This seems to indicate that when my spider go to https://finance.yahoo.com/news/onegold-becomes-first-company-offer-110000241.html found in https://finance.yahoo.com/sitemap/2020_03_all. It tried sending cookie to https://finance.yahoo.com/news/onegold-becomes-first-company-offer-110000241.html, but was redirected to consent accepting wall https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId=3_cc-session_05cc09ea-0bc0-439d-8b4c-2d6f20f52d6e.

I open this consent wall https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId=3_cc-session_05cc09ea-0bc0-439d-8b4c-2d6f20f52d6e in browser and found data consent accepting screen. When I clicked accept, it brought me to the correct site that I want to scrape. The scraping results also exactly the content in this consent screen.

I have tried setting COOKIES_ENABLED to True, but it did not work. So, is there anyway to bypass this accepting screen in scrapy?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I am facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing:
Open the consent page on network tab, then click on the give consent button. There you can identify the request that it sends when you give your consent. You can try replicating the same request using scrapy. May be this way your issue will be solved.
Other option would be to use scrapy-selenium to manually click that button and then scrapy can take over from there.